# How can I use one shader to apply different values for each object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Hierarchy I have 3 gameobjects.

For example the Cube if I will change the Outline width in the Inspector it will apply the change to all the three objects also to the Sphere and Cylinder.

But I want that if I change the Outline width on the Cube that it will change it only for the cube and if I will change the outline width for the sphere then only for the sphere.

[image: Outline]

This is the shader:

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'

Shader "Outlined/Silhouetted Diffuse" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (.5,.5,.5,1)
        _OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _Outline ("Outline width", Range (0.0, 0.1)) = .005
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" }

        Pass {
            Name "OUTLINE"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            Cull Off
            ZWrite Off
            ZTest Always
            ColorMask RGB // alpha not used

            // you can choose what kind of blending mode you want for the outline
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha // Normal
            //Blend One One // Additive
            //Blend One OneMinusDstColor // Soft Additive
            //Blend DstColor Zero // Multiplicative
            //Blend DstColor SrcColor // 2x Multiplicative

CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag

#include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                float4 color : COLOR;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : POSITION;
                float4 color : COLOR;
            };

            uniform float _Outline;
            uniform float4 _OutlineColor;

            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                v.vertex.xyz += v.color * _Outline;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.color = _OutlineColor;
                return o;
            }

            half4 frag(v2f i) :COLOR {
                return i.color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass {
            Name "BASE"
            ZWrite On
            ZTest LEqual
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            Material {
                Diffuse [_Color]
                Ambient [_Color]
            }
            Lighting On
            SetTexture [_MainTex] {
                ConstantColor [_Color]
                Combine texture * constant
            }
            SetTexture [_MainTex] {
                Combine previous * primary DOUBLE
            }
        }
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" }

        Pass {
            Name "OUTLINE"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            Cull Front
            ZWrite Off
            ZTest Always
            ColorMask RGB

            // you can choose what kind of blending mode you want for the outline
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha // Normal
            //Blend One One // Additive
            //Blend One OneMinusDstColor // Soft Additive
            //Blend DstColor Zero // Multiplicative
            //Blend DstColor SrcColor // 2x Multiplicative

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles xbox360 ps3
            ENDCG
            SetTexture [_MainTex] { combine primary }
        }

        Pass {
            Name "BASE"
            ZWrite On
            ZTest LEqual
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            Material {
                Diffuse [_Color]
                Ambient [_Color]
            }
            Lighting On
            SetTexture [_MainTex] {
                ConstantColor [_Color]
                Combine texture * constant
            }
            SetTexture [_MainTex] {
                Combine previous * primary DOUBLE
            }
        }
    }

    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Select each of the 3 objects and post screenshot of their Inspector in the comment section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An educated guess based on what you've said: you have a single material using your shader, which is shared between all three objects.

When you edit the parameters of the material, it's editing the shared material and so the changes are being applied to all of the objects using that material.

You have two solutions: the easiest one is to create multiple materials in your project with differing shader parameters. The alternative is to create a script that will apply your parameter changes to `GetComponent<Renderer>().material` at runtime, as this will create an instance of the material separate to other objects.